# How does a rule without commands, like "a.h: b.h", take effect in a make file

Tags: makefile

For example:

```
# I understand this rule,
# which will compile a.c if b.h has been updated due to some implicit rules and dependency.
a.o: b.h

# But I don't understand the rule below.
# In reality, if c.h is modified, then when you run "make a.o", you will re-generate a.o.
# What I don't get is that, in theory, since the rule does not update b.h
# and a.o relies on b.h only according to the rule above 
# (I know a.o relies on c.h, indirectly),
# a.o should not be re-generated, right?
b.h: c.h
```

I looked up the gnu make manual, but didn't find syntax explaining the behavior above.

Could anybody point it out?

Edit: I had the question when I read some article about how to write rules describing dependency of header files. My guess that a.o would be regenerated once c.h is modified (based on my understanding on that article) proven to be wrong. I just tried. a.o will not be regenerated in that case, which is also consistent with my thoughts. I will re-read that article to see why I had such misinterpretation about the article. Anyway, my apology. It was a wrong question.

Edit2: I finally found back [the article](http://www.cs.umd.edu/class/spring2002/cmsc214/Tutorial/makefile.html) that led me to the incorrect understanding. If you search "Vector.h: Foo.h", you can find the author delivered the wrong knowledge in that section. Be cautious! Sorry again that I took it as true without trying it before I asked question here.

Comment: Observe what happens if you change `c.h`, run `make`, and then run `make` again (without changing anything this time).  Does that clue you in to what is going on here?

Comment: Thanks Zack. Just a clarification for those read the post and get confused. "b.h:c.h" actually has no effect. That is, after you modify c.h and run make, the modification will not make a.o be regenerated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this text from the POSIX specification for make:

> If there are no commands listed for the target, the target shall be treated as up-to-date.

I don't really understand your comment about what happens.  If all three files `a.o`, `b.h`, and `c.h` exist, and `a.o` is *newer* than `b.h` (so doesn't need to be rebuilt based on the first target), but is *older* than `c.h` (so should in theory need to be rebuilt based on the second target), in fact, `a.o` will *NOT* be updated when you run make.

That's because of the above rule, where since there's no rule to build `b.h`, it's considered up to date and hence not modified, and so its (older than `a.o`) timestamp is compared, and `a.o` does not need to be updated.

If that's not what you mean, please clarify your question by providing exact observations (maybe with some example output shown).